# Google webfonts on website look terrible in Chrome, but only on Windows

Tags: google-chrome, fonts

The fonts on my [website](http://kiljano.se) look really ugly when using Chrome on Windows. When viewing my site with an Android tablet, it looks good. Viewing it in Chrome on a Mac also looks good.

What could be the problem and how can I fix this?

Comment: Looks fine on my Windows machine... Which **version** of Windows? Do you have **ClearType** enabled? Which version of Google Chrome? Please edit your question to include these details.

Comment: I have tried with and without clear type, latest version of chrome. Windos XP.

Comment: I noticed the same thing with my site in Chrome on Windows